# Ektron Content Selector tree comes up as empty

Tags: ektron

There is this frustrating issue:

The Content Selector on a smart form is coming up as empty for any smart form and any folder.

The right side content loads but the left side tree is gone.

What has happened to the content on this CMS? Because it's not an issue on other instances of ektron.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after much debugging into the backend/workarea controls.

The issue was this:
**The Root folder (id: 0) has no default template selected, this was a bug that broke the content tree control that Ektron uses.**  It had two templates in the list but neither of them had the radio button for "Default" checked.

It's a silent error and you wouldn't know until you get this side effect issue.